# Macbook Pro 2012 shutsdown suddenly at 25% battery

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery

I have a Macbook Pro Unibody Mid 2012 and used the battery for only 118 cycles.

Since a few weeks ago whenever I'm on battery and it reaches <25% my Macbook shuts down immediately (no warning, no saving, so all my work is gone if I let it happen)

I'm okay with battery losing 25% of its capacity! but shouldn't this be from the top? I mean it can just reach to 0 faster, or display warnings!

Battery is really working, it still holds for ~3 hours, and I just can't replace it yet (and also no warranty, no apple shop near me)

> Is there an application out there which can change my battery sensor functions and set 25% = 0% (I mean it works just like a normal Macbook with less capacity available on battery)?

`P.S. Already tried installing Yosemite, and resetting SMC`

When not on Battery:

```
Charge Information:
Charge Remaining (mAh): 5653
Fully Charged:  Yes
Charging:   No
Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 5653

Health Information:
Cycle Count:    118
Condition:  Normal
Battery Installed:  Yes
Amperage (mA):  0
Voltage (mV):   12529
```

When on Battery

```
Charge Information:
Charge Remaining (mAh): 5545
Fully Charged:  Yes
Charging:   No
Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 5696

Health Information:
Cycle Count:    118
Condition:  Normal
Battery Installed:  Yes
Amperage (mA):  -1149
Voltage (mV):   12361
```

Comment: when you took this screen shot you were not on battery power, but on the charger. Could we have one on battery power without charger. SMC reset could be tricky, double check and redo it.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD I added the Info when on battery, Also I already reset SMC like 2-3 times.

Answer (score 1):

Every battery in a MacBook has a battery processor, which, from time to time, should be recalibrated. Like this:
1. Fully charge your Mac
2. Use it until it dies
3. Once dead, wait at least 5 hours, no less, then plug it in and charge it to 100%, without using it.

The battery percentage reading on your Mac should now be more accurate.

If this doesn't fix it, don't but a new MacBook or give away this one, your MacBook just needs a new battery.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't tried this yet (leaving it for 5 hours after it shuts down), I will try this today.